# Having Trouble with creation of an Azure Sentinel Stealthwatch Log Analytics Query

Tags: azure, cisco, kusto-explorer, azure-sentinel

I'm working on a project to create a Stealthwatch (Cisco) Log Analytics query from a canned workbook query available from the Azure Sentinel portal (Data Connectors > Cisco Stealthwatch). I've added the function to my LA query section and it will run (depending on the time parameters - more on that later).

When I run the query within the Log Query window, it runs great. However, when trying to use the Analytics Rule Wizard, the same query errors out with the following error:

'extend' operator: Failed to resolve scalar expression named 'start'.

Included here is the simple query I'm running:

```
StealthwatchEvent
| where EventSeverity == "Critical"
```

And here is the complete function as supplied by the Data Connector from the Azure Sentinel workbook for Cisco Stealthwatch:

```
Syslog
| where SyslogMessage has 'Stealthwatch'
| extend EventVendor = 'Cisco'
| extend EventProduct = 'Stealthwatch'
| extend EventProductVersion = extract(@'Stealthwatch\|([0-9\.]+)\|', 1, SyslogMessage)
| mv-apply ExtractedFields = extract_all(@'\|(?P<key>[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)=(?P<value>[a-zA-Z0-9-_:/@.,#{}>< ]+)', dynamic(["key","value"]), SyslogMessage) on (
    project packed = pack(tostring(ExtractedFields[0]), tostring(ExtractedFields[1]))
    | summarize bag = make_bag(packed)
)
| evaluate bag_unpack(bag)
| extend EventStartTime=todatetime(start)
| extend EventEndTime=todatetime(end)
| project-rename EventOriginalUid=alarmID
                , EventSeverity=alarmSev
                , EventStatus=alarmStatus
                , EventType=cat
                , SrcDvcDomain=domain
                , DstIpAddr=dst
                , DstPortNumber=dstPort
                , EventMessage=msg
                , Protocol=proto
                , SrcGeoCountry=sourceHG
                , SrcHostSnapshot=sourceHostSnapshot
                , SrcIpAddr=src
                , DvcIpAddr=flowCollectorIP
                , DvcHostname=flowCollectorName
                , SrcUserName=sourceUser
                , DstUserName=targetUser
                , DstGeoCountry=argetHG
                , DstDvcHostname=targetHostname
                , DstHostSnapshot=targetHostSnapshot
| project-away start
             , end
             , SyslogMessage
```

I've narrowed it down to the "start" value in the one extend statement. Note when I adjust the time on the Rule wizard for the query period (I run the query every 15 minutes and lookup data from the last 15 minutes) it should pass that to the query time parameters - but I'm just not sure why it's failing. Sometimes when I adjust the time, it fails on the "end" value instead as reported by the error. I have also tried removing the two extend lines related to time altogether, but then the query dies on AlarmID in the next section.

(And yes, I am fairly new to this - I'm learning Kusto/Sentinel and Stealthwatch tuning and reporting on the fly here)

:)

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To follow up - it's almost like as I adjust the time for the query and if there are no relevant events for that time period then the query responds with the failure error above, either on the "start" or "end" value.

So for example, if I generate test actions from Stealthwatch and send them to syslog which in turn is ingested by Azure Sentinel, I can "see" the resulting alerts ingested right after by choosing last 30 minutes in the time range. However, as time elapses, I have to adjust the time range higher as it will error out once the ingested data ages out past 30 mins.

Comment: However, the query within the alert wizard doesn't follow exactly the same logic. With the parameters I set above in the query for 15 minutes, it errors out consistently in the validation process.